# Magnetic flux due to movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

How does the magnetic flux decrease in the example shown below if the rectangle moves down due to the gravitational force, and there is no friction. The surface $A$ of the rectangle nor the magnetic field $B$ changes right, so how does the magnetic flux decrease? The solution manual says it does so, but it does not explain why. The electrical resistance is also neglibible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that the rectangular block is conductive so that it completes the circuit (forms a closed loop of conductive wire). Consider the area of the conducting wire to the left of the rectangular block. Let's say that at t = 0 we have exactly the physical situation as provided in your picture. As time goes on, the gravitational force acting on the rectangular block makes it fall down the slope. Since the rectangular block is conductive and acts to complete the circuit, it moving down the slope does in fact decrease the area of the closed conductive wire as time goes on. Thus, the total magnetic flux as time goes on decreases.

Answer (score 0):

The area below the conducting rectangle changes decreases so the area in $\Phi=BA$ changes.

Comment: Of course, so stupid. I was focusing too much on the moving rectangle, instead of the circuit it closes.